# Does Application connection pooling override Tomcat connection pooling

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I want to maintain connection pooling into my java/spring application. For this i used spring configuration file. Which looks like this

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
  class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.jdbcurl}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="3"/> T
    <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
</bean>
```

This application war is hosted into tomcat. When i saw tomcat context.xml file which is set by some network team. Context.xml file also contain some configuration regarding the connection pooling.It looks like this

```
<Context>

<Resource name="jdbc/test" 
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
username="naveen"
password="12345"
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql:localhost:3306/cyl"
maxActive="15"
maxIdle="3"/>

</Context>
```

Now i have two question to asked
1) Which connection pool configuration will apply when application runs.
2) If we have multiple war a.war(with connection pool config), b.war(with out CPC), c.war(without CPC) then, will tomcat connection pool setting will apply to all application.
3) what can be max value for maxActive attribute.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to check your code, as it depends on how the code acquires the connection. If it does a jndi lookup for "jdbc/test", the tomcat provided one is used. Most likely though, it wires in the "dataSource" bean from spring, and that one is used.

Comment: Sure, I am not looking for jndi that means spring application connection pooling will be used. What about 2 and 3 question.